# How do you get a NOW() value in C# using the MySQL Connector?

Tags: c#, mysql

Is it possible in an easy way to get the NOW() timestamp from an UPDATE query? I'm trying to save the "lastupdated" value in the local cache, or is there in any way possible to get the exact MySQL server time which the update query was executed?

Best Regards; Görgen

Comment: It seems he needs the precise timestamp that the server recorded.

I can only think of following it up with a SELECT, sorry.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Because DateTime.NOW can be a different value than the database, being separate from the application code...

Comment: Using DateTime.Now on the client in a client server system is a big no no and source of future bugs.

Comment: One of the the features of Windows is that it keeps machines in the same domain very close to completely synchronized at all times.  In other words, it's a safe assumption that the SQL Server and web server will be running on the same clock.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: The database is MySQL, not SQL Server.  `NOW()` isn't supported on SQL Server.  And the OP could use MONO for hosting the web app...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The exact syntax might vary, but I know that both SQL Server and MySQL have ways to return the current time in both local and UTC form. In specific, SQL Server has SYSDATETIME and SYSUTCDATETIME.  You're right that either C# or MySQL could be running on non-Windows machines, but Erik has given no indication of this.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: The ANSI standard way of getting the current date/time is to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, supported by MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server... =)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: For SQL Server 2008, it's listed as a low-precision source, unlike SYSDATETIME.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetSystemDateandTimeValues

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, MySQL doesn't have functionality like Oracle's `RETURNING` or SQL Server's `OUTPUT` clause to be able to save a query by returning values from INSERT/UPDATE statements.  So that means two statements minimum...

> is there in any way possible to get the exact MySQL server time which the update query was executed?

The best I can think of is to define an audit column (they were standard approach at my previous work) for logging the timestamp when the record was updated.  In MySQL, you can [default the value so on update it is set to the timestamp value at that time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
  ADD COLUMN update_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

...then this gives you a specific column value to query.

Comment: My only concern here is that I believe it may allow specifying a value for the column, in which case its auditing function might be compromised.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Which is another reason why I recommend interaction via stored procedure, and restricting direct database access...

Comment: Agreed that the easiest (and probably best) way to handle this is by blocking all but SP access, and even then, limiting it by role.  If the table has to be exposed, then UPDATE and INSERT triggers would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to set a LastUpdated field in the database, either in the stored procedure or in a trigger.  Then you can read it back.